# When to use a negative x for finding limits at negative infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\cfrac{5x^2+6x}{\sqrt{16x^4-5x^2}}$$

My understanding is to always use a negative x when doing negative infinity limits. So the answer I got was $-\frac{5}{4}$. Why do you sometimes use negative x and other times use positive x? The answer is $\frac{5}{4}$.

Edit***
I forgot to add the square root for the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to change $x:=-x$ to solve the question:

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\cfrac{5x^2+6x}{\sqrt{16x^4-5x^2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\cfrac{5(-x)^2+6(-x)}{\sqrt{16(-x)^4-5(-x)^2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\cfrac{5x^2-6x}{\sqrt{16x^4-5x^2}}$$

Divide the top and bottom by $x^2$ to get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\cfrac{5-\frac{6}{x}}{\sqrt{16-\frac{5}{x^2}}}=\frac{5}{4}$$

Notice how I phrased it -- when you change $x$ to $-x$, you have to change every $x$ in the equation, as well as the limit. If you proceeded to divide by $x^2$ immediately, you should end up with

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\cfrac{5+\frac{6}{x}}{\sqrt{16-\frac{5}{x^2}}}=\frac{5}{4}$$

which is also the same thing, so for this particular question it shouldn't actually matter.

Just because a limit is to negative infinity does not mean the answer is negative; rather than "negative limit means negative answer" approach the question normally or employ a change of variables.

Comment: The last expression should have the limit as $x\to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Let $-1/x=h$

$$F=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{5x^2+6x}{\sqrt{16x^4-5x^2}}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\dfrac5{h^2}-\dfrac6h}{\sqrt{\dfrac{16}{h^4}-\dfrac5{h^2}}}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{h^4}(5-6h)}{h^2\sqrt{16-h^2}}$$

As $h\to0^+,\sqrt{h^4}=+h^2$ as $h\to0^+,h\ne0$ cancel out $h^2$

$$F=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{5-6h}{\sqrt{16-h^2}}=?$$